# Неправильное действие функции в python,pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Создаю игру , есть функция , которая выводит разные картинки на экран.

```
def spawn(argx,argy,cope1,cope2,name):
        global move_cof , score , spawnxrand , y1 , x1 , playSurface

        if argx >= x1 and argx <= x1 + 60 and argy >= y1 and argy <= y1 +40:
            score += 1
            argx = random.randrange(100, 550)
            argy = -10
            cope1 = argx - 10
            cope2 = argx + 10
        if move_cof:
            print (score)

            argy += 8

            if spawnxrand == 0:
                argx -= 5
                if cope1 == argx:
                    spawnxrand = 1
            if spawnxrand == 1:
                argx += 5
                if cope2 == argx:
                    spawnxrand = 0


            if argy == 420:
                argy = -10
                argx = random.randrange(50, 650)
                cope1 = argx - 10
                cope2 = argx + 10

            playSurface.blit(name,[argx, argy])
```

Потом эта функция вызывается в while True(что бы картинка показывалась)

```
while True: 
    spawn(spawnx, spawny, copy1, copy2, pie)
    pygame.display.flip()
    playSurface.fill(white)
    fpsController.tick(15)
```

Но при этом playSurface не хочет выводить на экран картинку(вывело только 1 раз,и встало , картинка не двигалась)
Весь код игры:

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
green = pygame.Color(0, 200, 100)
playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Марио")
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()

x1 = 200
y1 = 350
x2 = 400

score = 0
coffee = pygame.image.load("Bonus.png")
coffee = pygame.transform.scale(coffee,(28,18))
pie = pygame.image.load("Bonus2.png")
pie = pygame.transform.scale(pie,(28,18))
mario = pygame.image.load("Mario.png")
mario = pygame.transform.scale(mario,(60,40))
bk = pygame.image.load("Back.jpg")
bk = pygame.transform.scale(bk,(800,600))

t1 = time.clock()
white = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
black = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0) # Цвета
lightslateblue = pygame.Color(0, 150, 255)

move_cof = True
move_2 = False
move_3 = False
move_4 = False
spawnkill = True
fs = True
end = False
jumpsound = True

spawnx = random.randrange(100,550)
spawny = -20
spawnxrand = random.randint(0,1)

copy1 = spawnx - 10
copy2 = spawnx + 10


def spawn(argx, argy, cope1, cope2, name):
    global move_cof, score, spawnxrand, y1, x1, playSurface

    if argx >= x1 and argx <= x1 + 60 and argy >= y1 and argy <= y1 + 40:
        score += 1
        argx = random.randrange (100, 550)
        argy = -10
        cope1 = argx - 10
        cope2 = argx + 10
    if move_cof:
        print (score)

        argy += 8

        if spawnxrand == 0:
            argx -= 5
            if cope1 == argx:
                spawnxrand = 1
        if spawnxrand == 1:
            argx += 5
            if cope2 == argx:
                spawnxrand = 0

        if argy == 420:
            argy = -10
            argx = random.randrange (50, 650)
            cope1 = argx - 10
            cope2 = argx + 10

        playSurface.blit (name, [argx, argy])


def music():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
music()


def gameover():

    time2 = time.clock ()


    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gaO1Font = pygame.font.SysFont ('Garamond', 26)
    gaO1Surface = gaO1Font.render (" Ты проиграл! Время в игре: " + str (int ((time2 - t1) // 60)) + " минут ", True,red)
    gaO1Rectangular = gaO1Surface.get_rect ()
    gaO1Rectangular.midtop = (400, 200)
    playSurface.fill (black)
    playSurface.blit (gaO1Surface, gaO1Rectangular)

    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(3)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()




while True:

    gaO1Font = pygame.font.SysFont ('Garamond', 18)
    gaO1Surface = gaO1Font.render ("Твой счет: {0}".format(score), True,lightslateblue)
    gaO1Rectangular = gaO1Surface.get_rect ()
    gaO1Rectangular.midtop = (430, 50)
    playSurface.fill (black)





    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit ()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit ()
                sys.exit()



            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_2 = True

            if fs == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    move_3 = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_4 = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:


            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   move_2 = False



            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_4 = False


    if move_2 == True:
        x1 += 9
        if x1 > 520:
            x1 = 520

    if move_3==True:
        fs = False
        forjump = True
        fs = False
        if forjump == True:
            if jumpsound == True:
                pygame.mixer.init ()
                pygame.mixer.music.load ('jump.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play (loops=-1)
                jumpsound = False
        y1 -= 10
        if y1 == 250:
            move_3 = "Down"

    if move_3 == "Down":

        y1 += 10
        if y1 == 350:
            move_3 = False
            fs = True


    if move_4 == True:
        x1 -= 9
        if x1 < 15:
            x1 = 15

    if y1 == 450:
        y3 = y1
        pygame.mixer.stop ()
        music ()
        jumpsound = True

        fs = True
        move_3 = False





    playSurface.blit (bk, [0, 0])
    playSurface.blit (gaO1Surface, gaO1Rectangular)
    playSurface.blit (mario, [x1, y1])
    spawn(spawnx, spawny, copy1, copy2, pie)
    pygame.display.flip()
    playSurface.fill(white)
    fpsController.tick(15)
```

Как нужно исправить код , что бы картинка выводилась правильно?P.S. Ошибка в том , что  spawn(spawnx, spawny, copy1, copy2, pie) записано в глобальной переменной , поэтому в spawn всегда приходит одно и тоже значение , но как тогда исправить код?

Comment: а можно сократить код - локализовать место проблемы?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets , хорошо, я уже кстати решил эту проблему , через классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле , это намного легче реализовать с помощью классов . В данном случае , это бы выглядело так:

```
class spawn():
    def __init__(self,argx, argy, cope1, cope2, name,score):
        self.score = score
        self.argx = argx
        self.argy = argy
        self.cope1 = cope1
        self.cope2 = cope2
        self.name = name
        self.spawnxrand = random.randint (0, 1)

    def show(self):
        self.argy += 8
        if self.argx >= x1 and self.argx <= x1 + 60 and self.argy >= y1 and self.argy <= y1 + 40:
            self.argx = random.randrange (100, 550)
            self.argy = -10
            self.cope1 = self.argx - 10
            self.cope2 = self.argx + 10
        if self.spawnxrand == 0:
            self.argx -= 5
            if self.cope1 == self.argx:
                self.spawnxrand = 1
        if self.spawnxrand == 1:
            self.argx += 5
            if self.cope2 == self.argx:
                self.spawnxrand = 0

        if self.argy >= 420:
            self.argy = -10
            self.argx = random.randrange (50, 550)
            self.cope1 = self.argx - 10
            self.cope2 = self.argx + 10

        playSurface.blit(self.name, [self.argx, self.argy])
```

а для вывода на экран нескольких картинок можно сделать так:

```
all = [spawn(spawnx, spawny, copy1, copy2, coffee,score)]
fall2 = [spawn(spawnx2, spawny2, copy3, copy4,pie,score)]
while True: 
    for i in fall:
        i.show()

    for f in fall2:
        f.show()

    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsController.tick(15)
```

Comment: а в чем ошибка-то была?

Comment: В том , что картинка не выводилась на экран,но если всё сделать через классы , всё работает

Comment: Да я не об этом, реализация через классы это просто другой способ код описать, и решением ошибки сам по себе не является. Мне интересно узнать что не так было в коде в вопросе и что пришлось изменить чтобы ошибка пропала

Comment: Почитай мой вопрос , там я написал почему картинка не выводится . А вот как сделать что бы прошлый  данный код работал , я вообще не знаю .

Comment: Я всегда в spawn пишу одно и тоже значение переменных , а внутри функции , меняются не глобальные переменные , картинка не успевает прорисовываться потому что всегда одно и тоже значение в функцию кидают .

Comment: Теперь стало понятно :)